# Unable to get provider - rarely crash on kitkat

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-4.4-kitkat

Few times in the week i receive crash report in GP console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mypackage.MyProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.MyProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/mypackage-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/mypackage-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5018)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.MyProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/mypackage-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/mypackage-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5003)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(DexFile.java)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:326)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4514)
        ... 10 more
```

Also, after adding Firebase features to my project i start to receive same crash reports about *com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider*.

According to reports, this errors happens **only** on:

**Android 4.4** 98,7 %

Android 4.2 1,3 %

I've try all this [ClassNotFoundException for a ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303285/classnotfoundexception-for-a-contentprovider), but no result.

Is this really a system bug and every developer deals with it, or it's my error? I really want to stop annoying users. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case really looks like bug described [there in Android's Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56296).
There you got issue when user starting app immediately after apk update.

There is workaround from comments which could help you to prevent this bug:

```
public class DevToolsApplication extends Application {
private static final String TAG = "DevToolsApplication";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppLogger.i(TAG, "app start...");
        checkAppReplacingState();
    }

    private void checkAppReplacingState() {
        if (getResources() == null) {
            AppLogger.w(TAG, "app is replacing...kill");
            Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it causes "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application mypkg..App" instead.